# How to set XSRF-TOKEN cookie in koa2 app?

Tags: javascript, csrf, koa

I'm write node-koa2-angular app. And I need set XSRF-TOKEN cookie like in express app:

```
var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })
```

But in koa-csrf I cannot find this option and by default it's don't create cookie.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that [koa-csrf](https://github.com/koajs/csrf) does not create the cookie. Instead it introspects the cookie on the koa context at `ctx.session`. Check out where this happens in the [code](https://github.com/koajs/csrf/blob/master/src/index.js#L55).

You'll need to add an additional middleware like [koa-session](https://github.com/koajs/session) to create the cookie. Your implementation should look something like:

```
const session = require('koa-session');
const CSRF = require('koa-csrf');

// set the session keys and add session support    
app.keys = ['secret']
app.use(session({}, app))

// add the CSRF middleware
app.use(new CSRF());

// your middleware here (e.g. parse a form submit)
app.use((ctx, next) => {
  if (ctx.method === 'GET') {
    ctx.state.csrf = ctx.csrf;
  }
  return next();
});
```